# List of ALL Operator Properties and Solve For X Methods

Tags: big-list, computational-mathematics, online-resources

I am attempting to write code that can "solve-for-x" on any mathematical expression ranging from $x - 2 = 0 $ $ $ to $ $ $ 97x^{51} - 60^x = 1$, and all the way through expressions like $W=\int_{k<\wedge}[Dg][Da][D\psi][D\phi]\exp\left\{i\int{d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left[\frac{m^2_p}{2}R-\frac{1}{4}F^a_{\mu\nu}F^{a\mu\upsilon}+i\psi^i\gamma^{\mu}D_\mu\psi^i+\left(\psi^i_LV_{ij}\phi\psi_R^j + h.c.\right)-|D_\mu\phi|^2-V(\phi)\right]}\right\}$ and beyond (P.S. I just looked up big equation to exemplify my goal. I don't understand it's purpose, so please just don't ask about it).

What I am looking for is a webpage the contains a very very long list of all properties of all operators (including modulo and bitwise), and all techniques used to "solve for x" (or that are related to "solve for x") in any form. Preferably, I would prefer the list to have been created within the past 2 years, and contains every extrapolation (no matter how extraneous) on it. The reason for why I am looking for a list is so I can go through linearly, so that I don't miss anything.

Comment: Do you think what you are describing is finite? I doubt it.

Comment: As implied in the above passage, my end goal is create some code that can "solve-for-x" on anything, finite or infinite. So, yes, it can be infinite.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with any of a number of CAS? Macsyma, Sage, Mathematica, Maple, etc? Its a pretty tall order to look for such things on a Q&A site?

Comment: $x$ is not something you can solve for in your last example equation, FYI.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes and no. You are correct that it is most likely impossible to extract a single number or fixed set of numbers to represent X, however that is not necessarily what I am aiming at. Instead, I am just aiming at getting X onto one side of the equation. So actually, I do believe there is this kind of a solution to my last listed equation.